# Create Oracle users in a loop with default tablespace

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I try to execute this but it gives an error at the default tablespace. I want to give a default tablespace to the users I create but how?

```
BEGIN
  FOR USERNAME IN (SELECT studentname from students)
  LOOP
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE USER ' || USERNAME.studentname  || ' IDENTIFIED BY ' || USERNAME.studentname;
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DEFAULT TABLESPACE "USERS"'; 
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'TEMPORARY TABLESPACE "TEMP"';
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'GRANT STUDENT TO ' || USERNAME.studentname ;                                    
  END LOOP;
END;


Error report - ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement ORA-06512: at line 5 00900. 00000 - "invalid SQL
```

Comment: Which error exactly?

Comment: Specifying the error is useful.  Your first three statements look like they should all be part of a single statement.  You'd want a single `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ` that did the whole `CREATE USER` including the default and temporary tablespace.  Of course, you'd want to ensure that you have appropriate whitespace in your DDL statement (spaces before `DEFAULT` and `TEMPORARY` for example).

Comment: The first three lines should be a **single** statement. There is no valid SQL statement `default tablespace`

Comment: Error report -
ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement
ORA-06512: at line 5
00900. 00000 -  "invalid SQL statement"
*Cause:    
*Action:

Comment: When I make one statement of the first three, I get the following error           Error report -
ORA-00922: missing or invalid option
ORA-06512: at line 4
00922. 00000 -  "missing or invalid option"
*Cause:    
*Action:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to combine the first three statements into one and add in appropriate spaces.  You don't need the double-quotes around the tablespace names since you're using case-insensitive identifiers.

```
BEGIN
  FOR USERNAME IN (SELECT studentname from students)
  LOOP
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE USER ' || USERNAME.studentname  || ' IDENTIFIED BY ' || USERNAME.studentname ||
                      '  DEFAULT TABLESPACE USERS  
                        TEMPORARY TABLESPACE TEMP';
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'GRANT UNLIMITED TABLESPACE TO ' || USERNAME.studentname;
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'GRANT STUDENT TO ' || USERNAME.studentname ;                                    
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Personally, I'd always generate a string with the SQL statement and pass that string to `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`.  That makes it easy to do things like log the SQL statements that are executed or to log which statement failed.  That's going to make debugging far easier.